# Vue and Django mustache templating conflict

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, django-templates

I am planning to do a project with Vue in the frontend and Django in the backend, but they both use double curly braces `{{ }}` as their template tags. Is there an easy way to change one of the two to use some other custom templating tag?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vue has a parameter called [delimiters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters) which set the placeholder's delimiters. For example this way you'll set them to double square brackets:

```
new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    el: "#myapp",
    //...
})


<div>
   {{ djangoPlaceholder }}
   [[ vuePlaceholderValue ]]
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with Django templates?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to change the delimiters in Vue you can use the verbatim Django tag to prevent the braces from being interpreted:

```
{% verbatim %}
    {{ myvuevar }}
{% endverbatim %}
```

This is a quick and simple approach that might suffice. It has the disadvantage that you cannot render Django variables within the verbatim tags (of course).

Comment: Thanks. But I want both to be rendered.